# How can I run java class file using a script file in Linux at boot time?

Tags: java, linux, scripting

How can I run java class file using a script file in Linux at boot time?

I have some java class file .I want that file should run at boot time when machine restart.I want to write a Script file that run those of my java classes at machine startup.

Comment: How this question is duplicate. I dnt find any answer on these. I am not asking about "How to run Script at startup". My question is to run java class file using script .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What linux distro are you using?

If you use Ubuntu then you can take a look at the upstart deamon which handles the task of starting processes during boot.

In general you create a script under `/etc/init.d`, described in detail [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto)

Since i  only created bash scripts there and  i dont know much about Java this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162768/starting-java-processes-with-upstart) might be helpful